# Epochs in keras meaning?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

What does this mean?

```
Epoch 1/300
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3616 - acc: 
0.3707
```

I built a neural network in keras and this is what it displayed. Since I am new to the whole neural networks, I am learning by reading through the various examples available online. This one comes from a neural network built in keras.

Answer (score 2):

Since deep learning often separates training data into smaller batches when training, it is important to know when all the training examples have been processed a single time. This is called an epoch.

There is a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31157729/7082163

Comment: what does 7200/7200 mean and?

Comment: I believe that is the number of training examples you are training on. Do you know this number?

Comment: Yes it's 8000 training examples and 2000 for testing.

Answer (score 2):

What is your batch size, training set size (num imgs)? But essentially, from this I can tell that you have finished the first epoch on a fit keras call with verbose=1. You have 7200 steps per epochs, which will mean your model will see `(7200*batch_size)` imgs. This may or may not be your entire training set, for steps per epochs it is common practice to use a `steps_per_epoch = (training_set_size // batch_size)` to ensure your model sees the entire training set in each epoch.